# Environment variables (zsh terminal) installed through npm on MacOS 12.4 Monterey - SOLVED

Tags: npm, zsh, npm-install

**Background:**

Dear Stackoverflow community. I recently switched from Windows to MacOS and am at a loss how to configure environment variables. Many of the previous questions asked here are about bash instead of zsh.

**Goal:**

I am trying to install an npm package globally. For instance:

```
 npm install -g vercel
```

or any other package, and use it in my Visual Studio Code terminal (also zsh). If I want to deploy code I have to use 'npx vercel deploy' every time. I want to be able to use "vercel deploy" but instead I get:

```
zsh: command not found: vercel
```

**What I tried so far:**

- Installing the package in zsh and visual studio code terminals (didn't work)
- Setting the path equal on both VS and terminal: export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I learned that you need to add environment variabels to a .zshrc file. I don't seem to have a zshrc file. When I do:

```
sudo ~/.zshrc
Password: XXXXXX
sudo: /Users/vincent/.zshrc: command not found
```

I am getting another error.

I read in the zsh man file that you should use $HOME/.zshrc instead. Again I am getting the same errors:

```
vincent@Vincents-MacBook-Air-2 ~ % $HOME/.zshrc
zsh: permission denied: /Users/vincent/.zshrc
vincent@Vincents-MacBook-Air-2 ~ % sudo $HOME/.zshrc
sudo: /Users/vincent/.zshrc: command not found
```

**Update 1:**

@slebetman Thank you for your explanation. When I open the terminal I go to home via "cd $HOME" which puts me in in the home directory. However there is no way for me to create a .zshrc file in that directory. Neither via touch or vs code. I am getting the following error: "Unable to write file '/home/.zshrc' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, open '/home/.zshrc')"

**Update 2:**

I did manage to find the .zshrc file in visual studio code under /etc. I hope this will work. I was able to overwrite the file with Sudo and add environment variables to it.

Add this to the file .zshrc file under /etc and force overwrite it:

```
export vercel=/Users/vincent/.npm-global/bin/vercel
```

Screenshots below for those who will try in the future:

[Image with .zshrc file layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuqYh.png)

**Final remarks:**

I don't understand how it is so difficult to add environment variables on Mac while everything else is so easy.

I have read many different questions on stackoverflow, and I can't seem to solve it. Also since I am a newbie I am not allowed to comment on there so I post here in the hope that anyone can help me :)

Best,
Vincent

Comment: `.zshrc` is a plain text file (like javascript or css code) and you can create it in any code editor. If it does not exist it simply means you have not customized your zsh. It must be in your user's home directory (`$HOME` or in other words `~` which means exactly the same thing as `$HOME`). It is the file your zsh shell will execute first before giving you the command prompt. Therefore you can write all your `export PATH=...` or `export JAVA_HOME=...` in that file

Comment: Note that you don't execute .zshrc. It is a config file, not a script (even though it is technically a script). You don't do `sudo ~/.zshrc` because that's not how you are supposed to use it. To use .zshrc you open (or create) `.zshrc` in a code editor like Visual Studio Code. Add your environment variables in the `.zshrc` file. Save the file in your home directory. Then the next terminal you open will have the environment variables

Comment: Did you already read the section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_ in the zsh-man-page? From this, you can choose which is the best place to set the environment variables. Perhaps it is ~/.zshenv, but your requirements could be different.

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for your explanation. When I open the terminal I go to home via "cd $HOME" which puts me in in the home directory. However there is no way for me to create a .zshrc file in that directory. Neither via touch or vs code. 
I am getting the following error: 

 "Unable to write file '/home/.zshrc' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, open '/home/.zshrc')"

Comment: Consider keeping `.zshenv` idempotent, though, as it is sourced by *all* shells (even non-interactive ones). Don't add to `PATH`, for example, as you'll just be duplicating things that your login shell and/or parent interactive shell already did.

Comment: `ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket` - This means you've accidentally created a named pipe (which is accessible using the socket API instead of the file API - the same as TCP/IP sockets) with the name `.zshrc`. Delete that "file" (on Unix lots of things are "files" including keyboards, network cards, hard disk etc.) before creating a new one.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot guys!

I got the environment variable to work an was able to run $vercel now :)

Comment: about the same file .zshrc in a different place, I don't think I was able to create it in the end so it shouldn't be an issue. But ill keep it in mind.

Comment: @chepner ok thanks a lot, so you mean it is a security risk?

Comment: Not really a security risk, but some environment settings are intended to be made *once* and inherited, not reexecuted for every shell. My standard example are `zstyle` commands: the things they set aren't inherited by child shells, but you may want them in *every* shell, interactive or not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you do:

```
npx vercel deploy
```

Npm will execute `vercel` for you **without installing it**. It does that by temporarily downloading vercel. If you want to run `vercel` directly without using `npx` then simply don't use `npx`. Install it instead:

```
npm install -g vercel
```

The `-g` flag installs the module globally and if the module has a CLI it will be available globally as well (note that depending on your setup you may need admin/sudo privileges to use the `-g` flag). Now you can run `vercel` by simply typing:

```
vercel deploy
```

This works in all operating systems supported by node.js and npm. That means you can even do this in Windows. In fact I use npm to distribute my tools in a simple cross-platform way so I don't have to support multiple package managers like chocolatey (Windows), homebrew (Mac OS), deb (Debian based distros), rpm (Redhat based distros) etc. (npm does not require your software to be written in node.js - I have published packages on npm written in tcl and bash).